# gorm read json from interface type of model

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a model as

```golang
type FlowTransaction struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name                          string
    PartnerTransactionReferenceId string
    ReconData                     interface{} `gorm:"type:jsonb"`
    DestinationAccountNumber      *string
    DestinationIfsc               *string
    Amount                        uint64
    PartnerId                     uint
    FlowId                        uint
    SelfSettle                    bool
    IsSandbox                     bool
}
```

while reading from my postgres database, in my `ReconData` I am getting message as `unreadable could not resolve interface type`. I tried implementing scan and value methods.

```golang
type customJson interface{}

func (j *customJson) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    return Scan(value, j)
}

func (j customJson) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return Value(j)
}


func Scan[dtoType any](value interface{}, model *dtoType) error {
    bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal JSONB value:", value))
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, model)
    return err
}

func Value[dtoType any](j dtoType) ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(j)
}
```

but it is giving an error as `invalid receiver type customJson (pointer or interface type)`. Do you guys have any idea how can I go about solving this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: tried converting interface type to []byte, but that did not help as well.

Comment: The error you're getting suggests that `customJson` (which according to golang conventions should be `customJSON`) is an interface, not a type. You can't implement methods on an interface - much less pointer receiver methods. An interface is a description of any type that implements a given contract, it's not an implementation thereof

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem got it. then how can i go about solving my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the JSON type.

```
import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type JSON json.RawMessage

func (j *JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal JSONB value:", value))
    }

    result := json.RawMessage{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result)
    *j = JSON(result)
    return err
}

func (j JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if len(j) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return json.RawMessage(j).MarshalJSON()
}
```

and in model struct :

```
type FlowTransaction struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name                          string
    PartnerTransactionReferenceId string
    ReconData                     JSON `type:jsonb`
    DestinationAccountNumber      *string
    DestinationIfsc               *string
    Amount                        uint64
    PartnerId                     uint
    FlowId                        uint
    SelfSettle                    bool
    IsSandbox                     bool
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because gorm use [pgx](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#PostgreSQL), you can use [pgtype](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype) package. there's type [JSONB](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/jsonb.go#L8)

So your model look like this

```golang
import (
    ...
    "github.com/jackc/pgtype"
    ...
)

type FlowTransaction struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name                          string
    PartnerTransactionReferenceId string
    ReconData                     pgtype.JSONB `gorm:"type:jsonb"`
    DestinationAccountNumber      *string
    DestinationIfsc               *string
    Amount                        uint64
    PartnerId                     uint
    FlowId                        uint
    SelfSettle                    bool
    IsSandbox                     bool
}
```

Comment: sure. will try it once.